# Is it possible to have Nashorn load scripts from classpath?

Tags: java, clojure, nashorn

Is it possible to have Nashorn's `load` method use the project's classpath when resolving URIs?

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
(defn create-engine
  "Creates a new nashorn script engine and loads dependencies into its context."
  [dependencies]
  (let [nashorn (.getEngineByName (ScriptEngineManager.) "nashorn")
        scripts (map #(str "load('" % "');") dependencies)]
    (.eval nashorn "var global = this;")
    (doseq [script scripts] (.eval nashorn script))
    nashorn))

(def app "public/javascripts/app.js") ; in /resouces, on classpath


; resulting exception:
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: 
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: 
Cannot load script from public/javascripts/app.js in <eval> at line number 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute path should always start with a slash, `"/public/javascripts/app.js"`, but I'm not sure if `load()` loads off the classpath, if it doesn't you may have to use `eval(Reader)` method and construct the reader yourself

EDIT:

You need to use the opening slash for classpath resources if the path is absolute within the jar. No slash means relative to the particular class you're calling this from. You should get an `InputStream` for the resource and eval a reader, in Java it would look like this:

```
nashorn.eval (new InputStreamReader (getClass().getResourceAsStream("/public/javascripts/app.js")));
```

I don't want to translate this to clojure since that's bound to end in failure.

EDIT2:

Well then here's an attempt then:

```
(defn create-engine
  "Creates a new nashorn script engine and loads dependencies into its context."
  [dependencies]
  (let [nashorn (.getEngineByName (ScriptEngineManager.) "nashorn")]
    (.eval nashorn "var global = this;")
    (doseq [dependency dependencies] (.eval nashorn (new InputStreamReader (.getResourceAsStream String dependency))))
    nashorn))
```

I shall not be held responsible if this starts the nuclear war or something

Comment: Thanks for following-up on your path comment. In case you couldn't tell, I'm a complete novice when it comes to Java. :)

Answer (score 9):

Nashorn's `load()` method actually supports taking a URL prefixed with `classpath:`. It will load the file following that prefix from the classpath. Check out the source - http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sundar/8025629/webrev.01/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/Context.java.html line 502.

Comment: this did seem to work for loading a script out of `src\test\resources` which was on my clsaspath. however when I tried to load the js file out of a jar i find that the nashorn classloader is very restricted. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30251930/329496 which gives some suggestions about this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use clojure.java.io/resource

```
(def nashorn (.. (javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.) (getEngineByName "nashorn")))
(.eval nashorn (clojure.java.io/reader (clojure.java.io/resource "jvm-npm.js")))
```

Make sure the resource folder is configured in your lein project:

```
:resource-paths ["src/resources"]
```