# Nashorn in JDK10 Java.type() strange behavior

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

**Hello everybody,**
I'm writing an application to make calculations based on information stored inside old .dbf files from an old fox-pro for MS-DOS system, those calculations generate journal entries to use in the new book keeping - ERP system; users should be able to add/delete/modify the generation of entries on the fly. So, my solution was using Nashorn script engine: I have a folder defined in the app settings, then the app scans all .js files inside that folder which extends an abstract class (Totalizer) which generates the entries, and voila.
All sounds good, except that It doesn't work B-)
The source code of the Totalizer abstract class is:

```java
public abstract class Totalizer {

    private List<Expense> expenses;
    private List<Employee> distribution;

    /**
     * 
     * @return Id of the totalizer.
     */
    public abstract String getId();

    /**
     * @return Descriptive title of the totalizer.
     */
    public abstract String getTitle();

    /**
     * Creates the JournalEntry based upon a single DBF record.
     *
     * @param record dbf record.
     * @return List of journal entries.
     * @throws java.lang.Exception if any exception is thrown.
     */
    public abstract List<JournalEntry> totalize(
            DbfRecord record) throws Exception;

    public void setExpenseMapping(List<Expense> expenses) {
        this.expenses = expenses;
    }

    public void setDistribution(List<Employee> distribution) {
        this.distribution = distribution;
    }

}
```

Then, I have the script files, I'm sharing one of them since all are similar:

```js
/**
* Vacations expenses entry:
*/
var BenefVacaciones = Java.extend(Totalizer, {
    getId : function(){
        return "diar.BenefVaca";
    },
    getTitle : function(){
        return "Beneficios: Vacaciones.";
    },

    totalize : function(record){
        //TODO: implement this method.
        return null;
    }
});

/*
* Creates a new instance of BenefVacaciones.
*/
function createInstance() {
    return new BenefVacaciones();
}
```

Then, the class that "loads" the script, is an implementation of Task, that does the following:

```java
//Loads a script and returns totalizer implementation.
public Totalizer loadScript(File aFile) throws IOException, ScriptException{
    //creates the engine.
    var engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
    //reads script from FileReader
    try(var reader = new FileReader(aFile)){
        var obj = engine.eval(reader);
        if(obj instanceof Invocable){//if obj is invocable
            var inv = (Invocable)obj;//casts to invocable
            var ret = inv.invokeFunction("createInstance");//invoke
            if(ret instanceof Totalizer){//if invoked function is Totalizer
                return (Totalizer)ret;//return that totalizer
            }else if(ret == null){//if invoked function returns null
                throw new NullPointerException("return value is null.");
            }else{//if returns non-null value but isn't Totalizer
                throw new ScriptException("Function createInstance won't return Totalizer");
            }
        }else if(obj == null){//WATCH: If engine.eval returns null
            throw new NullPointerException("engine.eval returns null.");
        }else{//If engine.eval returns non-invocable value.
            throw new ScriptException("Cannot get invocable object.");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this code as is should throw a

> ScriptException, ReferenceError: "Totalizer" is not defined in <eval>
>   at line ...

But here is the funny thing, if I add the following line to the .js script file:

```js
var Totalizer = Java.type('com.fossc.diar.onfalo.jsapi.Totalizer');
```

Then, engine.eval returns null, code execution falls into Totalizer line with comment "WATCH: If engine.eval returns null", when I expect to get an Invocable object, or the instance of any other object at least.
No exception is thrown, so I don't have any information.
I've also tried adding the following line to the loadScript method right after engine declaration:

```java
engine.put(
    "Totalizer",
    jdk.dynalink.beans.StaticClass.forClass(Totalizer.class));
```

But it returns null. Also tried adding a class filter that always return true, but that neither works. I've been searching for a solution to this but nothing seems to work, when I use Java.type() in ANY script, engine.eval returns a null object instead of an Invocable instance, even testing engine.eval("var x = Java.type(\'java.lang.String\');") returns null.
For user interface reasons, I'm calling the loadScript function from a JavaFX Task implementation, so I've found that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945507/java-nashorn-classnotfoundexception-java-type and I've tried setting the currentThread.contextClassLoader to Totalizer.class.getClassLoader()
Am I doing something wrong?
I'm using the following software:

- IDE: Apache Netbeans 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708).
- Project type: JavaFX Application Project.
- Oracle JDK 10

  - java --version: java 10.0.1 2018-04-17

    - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
    - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
  - javac --version: javac 10.0.1
- S.O.: Manjaro Linux 17.1.11 Hakoila.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's a bit embarrasing but I've found the error.

```
var obj = engine.eval(reader);
```

Always return null on this case, It only returns a value if I write something like:

```
engine.eval("2+2");
```

The error is that the engine itself is the Invocable object. So, I only need to cast engine, not eval result:

```
engine.eval(reader);
var inv = (Invocable)engine;
var ret = inv.invokeFunction("createInstance");
if(ret instanceof Totalizer){
    return (Totalizer) ret;
}else if(ret == null){
    throw new NullPointerException("createInstance returns null.");
}else{
    throw new ScriptException("createInstance dont return Totalizer.");
}
```

And everything works OK. Of course, in that case, if I do engine.eval without engine.put or Java.type, then the ReferenceError arises because Totalizer doesn't exist in the script side, giving the appareance that I only need to "import" that class. But engine.eval for that script should always return null, so when the error is fixed it's what it do: returns null.